# Refresh controls when List changes

Tags: list, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

Visual Studio 2012 with DevExpress and Entity.

I have a user-control which contains a number of `TextEdit-controls`.
Each control is bound to one property of each item in a list using `Databinding.` (so each Item in the list has one property bound to one control)
The class which creates the list has `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented.

**Problem :** If the list is changed (a new Entity.ToList() ) the controls do not refresh.
According to what I found already on the internet, this is 'normal' since the controls are bound to an Item in a certain list, and that List gets created anew each time.

So how do I get my controls to refresh when the List itself changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an ObservableCollection<> data-structure for the list of entities that keep changing. I used this to effect for grid-refresh in a C# WPF project of mine.